# Storing permissions in session

Tags: php, database, session, session-variables

My scenerio:
I have users mapped to products.
The user can access product only through productIds.
An user cannot access products which are not assigned to him. 
To do this, I am thinking of storing the productIds for an user into a session variable. So, when the user tries to access any product, it checks this session variable and allows only if it is there.
But the problem here is;
The admin may assign new productId to this user but the user will not be able to access until and unless the session variable is updated/re-initialised.
And I don't want to query to database!! 

Please suggest in php context!!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using servlets etc. Then dont save them in session. save these permissions in servlet context. values stored in servletcontext is available to all sessions. when admin assigns new products update it in the servletcontext along with the database. And retreive it when required.